# Modifying Data Labels from Center to Above in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make some revisions to my DataLabels.

I would like the column width (Down, Up and Total) to match the size of the text. I would also like to make the data label text bolded and easier to see.

Does anyone know the best method to do this given my code and the existing chart that I have right now?

Thanks!

[image]

```
Sub Waterfall()
'
' Waterfall Macro
'

'
Range("A7").Select
Dim rngData As Range
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim rngToSelect As Range
Dim srs As Series
Dim i As Long


Set rngData = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

Set rngToSelect = Range(rngData.Cells(1, 1), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, 1))
For intCounter = 1 To rngData.Columns.Count
    If rngData.Cells(1, intCounter).Value <> "Values" Then
        Set rngToSelect = Union(rngToSelect, Range(rngData.Cells(1, intCounter), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, intCounter)))
    End If
Next intCounter

rngToSelect.Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngToSelect
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 75
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Blank").Select
    Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
For Each srs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    For i = 1 To UBound(srs.Values)
        srs.Points(i).HasDataLabel = srs.Values(i) > 0
        Next i
        Next srs
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Blank").DataLabels.ShowValue = False
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Down").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Up").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)
    ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(3).Select
    Selection.delete

    'Remove Gridlines
     Dim axs As Axis
     For Each axs In ActiveChart.Axes
        axs.HasMajorGridlines = False
        axs.HasMinorGridlines = False
    Next
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you tried recording the macro while doing the changes manually you want and then understanding the code and re-using it for your purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change your data laebls text to bold try the following command:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection("Down").DataLabels.Font.Bold = True
```